# Invoke a activity method inside a fragment method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am kind of new using on this. Maybe I am doing something really stupid.

My question is: **There is a way of getting a method of activity inside of a fragment method?**

```
public class MyMusic extends Fragment {

    private static  final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;
    SongScreen songScreen = new SongScreen();

   static ArrayList<Song> songList = new ArrayList<Song>();;
    ListView songView;
    String songTitle, songArtist, durationSong, songAlbum;
    Song currentSong;
    int position;

    public MyMusic()
    {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_music, container, false);

        //List View
        songView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_music);
        songList = new ArrayList<Song>();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
            }else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
            }
        } else {
            accessfiles();
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void accessfiles(){

      //  songList = new ArrayList<Song>();

        Cursor song = getMusic();
        SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this.getContext(), songList);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdt);

        //When you click on the item pass to a new fragment with all the info
        songView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String songTitle = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleSong)).getText().toString();
                String songArtist = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artistSong)).getText().toString();
                String durationSong = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songDuration)).getText().toString();
                 Song currentSong = songList.get(position);
                String songAlbum = currentSong.getAlbum();
                passingToScreen(songTitle,songArtist,durationSong,songAlbum);
                //Path have the path of the song
                String path = currentSong.getPathSong();
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).playerStart(path ,currentSong);



    }});
    }
    private void passingToScreen(String songTitle, String songArtist, String durationSong, String songAlbum) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("songTitle", songTitle);
        bundle.putString("songArtist", songArtist);
        bundle.putString("durationSong", durationSong);
        bundle.putString("songAlbum", songAlbum);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        songScreen.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layoutCM,
                songScreen,
                songScreen.getTag()).commit();

    }

    public Cursor getMusic(){
        Context context = getContextOfApplication();
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor songcursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, null, null, null);


        if (songcursor != null && songcursor.moveToFirst()){
            int songId = songcursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int songTitle = songcursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int songArtist = songcursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int songAlbum = songcursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
            int songDuration = songcursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
            int pathSong = songcursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

            do{
                Long currentId = songcursor.getLong(songId);
                String currentTitle = songcursor.getString(songTitle);
                String currentArtist = songcursor.getString(songArtist);
                String currentAlbum = songcursor.getString(songAlbum);
                Long currentDuration = songcursor.getLong(songDuration);
                String currentPath = songcursor.getString(pathSong);

                songList.add(new Song(currentId, currentTitle, currentArtist, currentDuration, currentAlbum, currentPath ));
            }
            while (songcursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return songcursor;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST: {
                if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                   if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                           Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                       accessfiles();
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void getNext(Song currentSong) {

        if (songList.contains(currentSong))
        {
           int position1 = songList.indexOf(currentSong);
            if(position1 > songList.size())
            {
                String nextSong = songList.get(0).getPathSong();
                Song next = songList.get(0);
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).playerStart(nextSong, next);


            }else{
                String nextSong = songList.get(position1+1).getPathSong();
                Song next = songList.get(position1 + 1);
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).playerStart(nextSong, next);
                }
            }
        }



    public void getPrevious(Song currentSong) {
        int position = (int) (currentSong.getID() - 1);
        if(position < 0)
        {
            String previousSong = songList.get(songList.size()).getPathSong();
            Song previous = songList.get(songList.size());
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).playerStart(previousSong, previous);

        }else{
            String previousSong = songList.get(position).getPathSong();
            Song previous = songList.get(songList.size());
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).playerStart(previousSong, previous);
        }

    }
}
```

This is what I am trying to do. But I know I can't do " `((MainActivity)getActivity()).playerStart(previousSong, previous);`" but can I do to bring my currentsong and path to my main activity?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "But I know I can't do " ((MainActivity)getActivity()).playerStart(previousSong, previous);"" -- why not?

Comment: Yes, you can do it.((MainActivity)getActivity()).playerStart(previousSong, previous);

Comment: When I run the project give me this erro: 

 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.filip.justplay.MainActivity.playerStart(java.lang.String, com.example.filip.justplay.Song)' on a null object reference

Comment: As others have said, that should probably work.  Could you post MainActivity (if it's a large file, probably just posting `playerStart()` method with anything that might initialize it or variables in it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

1.Use EvenBus for that.
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

2. In your fragment:

   ```
   public AppCompatActivity mActivity;
       @Override
       public void onAttach(Context context) {
           super.onAttach(context);
           this.mActivity = (BaseActivity) context;
       }
   ```

and call after :

```
((MainActivity)mActivity).playerStart(previousSong, previous);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have to do some alterations but your answer helps me a lot.

`public static AppCompatActivity mActivity;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mActivity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    }`

Comment: you shouldn't use static  for mActivity, maybe it'll be leak memory